# Cleaning up a few of our Low-voted closed Questions

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions

Recently we seem to be attracting much more 'new' (or new to the workplace) users, whether or not this is because of our increased amount of hot questions in the ticker or not is beyond me, but in either case I think this would be a good time to clean up some of our 'bad' questions, these are the ones that are voted into the negatives, closed, with no chance of saving.

I think we should be doing this to ensure that any and all new users who come to the workplace don't mistakenly fall into thinking that these are example of OK questions because we have still got them around.

Therefore I will be posting a List of the questions I think we should be drawing attention to to get deleted or saved as a question per answer (yes the irony is lovely), please vote accordingly and feel free to tell me I'm wrong if you disagree with my judgement!

Answer (score 3):

[how-would-you-define-invoiceable-software-rd-and-likewise](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11076/how-would-you-define-invoiceable-software-rd-and-likewise) - This is yet another list question asking what is and isn't ok to charge your client for.

The question itself has been knocked down to -6 with 0 upvotes and i do not think it can be saved to be on topic for us here at the workplace. It could potentially be on topic at a site about freelancing or contracting but I don't think such a site exists.

Therefore I will be throwing a delete vote at this question too.

Answer (score 2):

[IT-hiring-management-just-wants-a-warm-body](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13208/it-hiring-management-just-wants-a-warm-body) - The question on this is 'What are some things that every lazy IT person doesn't want to do?'

It has already been decided that this is off topic, and it has been knocked down to -7 with 0 upvotes.

I don't think this question can be saved as it is a list question about what people don't like. This question is basically a poll or discussion question that serves as a bad example of what is expected of a good question.

It already has 1 delete vote (from before this post was even made) so requires only a little bit more intervention to get this one buried.